# understand the different construction of a std::string_view

Tags: c++

[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1fff2790c52c68b)

> The string_view family of template specializations provides an
> efficient way to pass a read-only, exception-safe, non-owning handle
> to the character data of any string-like objects with the first
> element of the sequence at position zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

std::unordered_map<std::string_view, int> create_map()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string_view, int> umap;
  std::string s1("s1");
  auto s2_bad = new std::string("s2");

  umap.emplace(std::make_pair(s1, 1));       // doesn't work b/c sv points to local variable
  umap.emplace(std::make_pair(*s2_bad, 2)); // Q1> why doesn't this work?
  
  umap.emplace(std::make_pair("s3", 3)); // Q2> why does this work?
  
  auto s4_bad = new std::string("s4_bad");
  umap.emplace(std::make_pair(s4_bad->c_str(), 4)); // this works
  
  return umap;
}
int main()
{
  auto abc_map = create_map();
  for(const auto&[key, value]: abc_map)
  {
    std::cout << "key: " << key << std::endl;
    std::cout << "value: " << value << std::endl;
    
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
key: s3
value: 3
key: $
value: 2
key: s4_bad
value: 4
key: $
value: 1
```

**Question 1**> Why doesn't `s2_bad` work here? Even if it points to an allocated address space.

**Question 2**> Why does the insertion of string literal "s3" work here? Even if it is defined within a scope of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**: `std::make_pair(*s2_bad, 2)` will create a `std::pair<std::string, int>`, so the pair has a distinct temporary `std::string`, unrelated to the string `s2_bad` points to. Then, a `std::string_view` will be constructed from this temporary, which will be promptly destroyed. So the moment `umap.emplace(std::make_pair(*s2_bad, 2));` finishes, the `string_view` is invalid. If you'd like to avoid this copy (and the associated lifetime problems), you can use `std::ref(*s2_bad)` instead of `*s2_bad`.

**Question 2**: String literals have `static` lifetimes, i.e. their contents are stored in the read-only sections of binaries instead of in the stack, so holding a pointer to a string literal and returning from the function containing the string literal does not pose any dangling pointer problems.